# Echo current number of row

Tags: php, mysql

My $num_rows echos the total row count but I want the current row number.

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM texts ORDER BY id desc');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
?>
<tr class="alt">
    <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['title']; ?></td>
    <td><a href="<?php echo $row['orginal']; ?>">Original</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">@English</a></td>
    <td><a href="#"><?php echo $num_rows; ?></a></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

why you should not use a increment variable to count the loop turns inside while?

```
$tmpCount = 1;
while() {

   $tmpCount ++;
}
```

Is this helpful to you? or are you expecting the physical row number of from database?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to just number the rows returned by the query (instead of using the actual ID - `$row['id']` presumably), you can just increment a number with each row:

```
$num_rows = 0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $num_rows++;
  // ...
```

Comment: The thing is that if I remove one row then the count will be wrong with $_row['id']

Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

This works, but when sorting, the number gets locked in and doesn't return to the natural sort.  The initial sort will be 1, 2, 3 but when clicking on the column to sort, whatever row is associated with the first sort will stay with it and the new sort will not have the num_rows in order!